# Выборка по полю типа timestamp записей за прошлый месяц

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

В базе есть поле `created_at`, которое содержит метку времени в `timestamp`. Мне нужно выбрать записи за прошлый месяц.

Как это сделать?

Comment: а как Вы уже пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: @lDrakonl я пробовал MONTH(`created_at`) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(`created_at`) = YEAR(NOW()), но это выражение из mysql и оно не работает, а как сделать в postgresql я не могу найти

Comment: Добавте Ваш комментарий в вопрос, и лучше даже полный запрос. Что не работает? Если расматривать логику вашего выражения, независимо от ДБ, возврат будет за текущий месяц. И судя по комментариям в ответе, добавте также структуру таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from tm
 where created_at >= date_trunc('month',current_timestamp - interval '1 month')
   and created_at <  date_trunc('month',current_timestamp)
```

Comment: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer >= timestamp with time zone
SQL-состояние: 42883
Подсказка: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Символ: 49 Вот что пишет

Comment: @Ricco381 Вы же сами сказали, что у вас поле в типе данных `timestamp`, почему же у вас в сообщении об ошибке сказано, что оно `integer` ? Если у вас там unixtime в виде числа, то вам надо обернуть дополнительно все в `extract(epoch from date_trunc(...)) что бы даты в виде чисел получить _перед сравнением_